# python Queue implementation

Tags: python-3.x, queue, global-variables

im trying to implement a queue in python, enQueue updates the queue but im comfused as to why deQueue wont update the queue

```
def enQueue(toDo,myQueue):
   myQueue += [toDo] 
   return myQueue

def deQueue(myQueue):
   if myQueue != []:
      return myQueue[1:]

def makeQueue():
    return[]


def main()

   football = event("10-10-2019","12:00","pitch")
   enQueue(football, getdone)
   print(getdone)
   deQueue(getdone)
   print(getdone)
```

both print statements give the same output

Comment: Can you show how are you using these funcs in your code?

Comment: just updated it now     .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `myQueue += [toDo]` is done in-place the effect of that operation persists after the function call.

`deQueue` does not perform it in place so after the call has been made, the `queue`, which you represent as a list, has not been updated.

---

You need to make a decision on if you want your functions to alter the queue you pass in-place or if they return a new one.

If you want an in-place approach, use `append` and `pop(0)` and return `None` (note though, that `pop(0)` is O(n) when you represent the Queue with a list).

In the opposite camp, just add the list or slice it and assign its return value to another name.

Comment: how can i make deQueue perform it in place?

Comment: the codes  part a project using Imperative style so i cant use append

Comment: @eire You don't  "return queue" in either case, since you discard the result anyway. You modify it in place with myqueue.pop(0)

Comment: @eire if you have to use imperative style, you should then use list slices (or del operator) as   Jim says. For example myqueue=myqueue[1:] I am not even sure how far to help you, because if you have to ask this, you possibly would be better off trying to understand how  basic functions  work. Plus, of course the fact that you haven't bothered accepting any of the answers to your previous questions does not seem to indicate you understand them.